# Adding elements to linked list inside a linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to create a small list for each element in a main list. I have the main list working fine but I don't know how to access and add elements to the small list.

```
struct smallList
{
    char data;
    struct smallList *next;
};

struct bigList
{
    char data;
    struct bigList *next;
    struct smallList *head;
} *root;
```

When I add stuff to the main list, I declare for each new node:

```
newNode->head = NULL;
```

I use this function to get the current pointer to an element in main list:

```
struct bigList *pointer = getPointer(root, value);
```

Then, to add stuff to its `smallList| using that pointer. I pass along`pointer->head` to this function. And its not working.

```
insert(pointer->head, value)
```

Comment: Learn how to pass a *pointer by-address* (i.e. a pointer to a pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WhozCraig suggests, you can resolve your problem using a pointer to a pointer.  Something like this:

```
void insert(struct smallList **head, char value)
{
    *head = newSmallList(value, *head);
}
```

`newSmallList` would be something like:

```
struct smallList *newSmallList(char value, struct smallList *rest)
{
    struct smallList *result = malloc(sizeof(struct smallList));
    result->next = rest;
    result->data = value;
    return result;
 }
```

The problem with your current setup is that you are passing the *value* of the pointer->head field (which happens to be null) to the function, when what you want is to alter what is stored in the field.  Here is a program using integers that illustrates a similar mistake:

```
void setFive(int i)
{
    i = 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    int myInt = 7;
    setFive(myInt);
    printf("%d\n", myInt); /* still 7! */
    return 0;
}
```